# JSONArray format in POST Request

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am trying to send a **list of items** in the following **format** in a POST request using Volley but server is receiving null.

[image]

Here is my Model Class:

```
public class SaveSettingsBO {
private int Id;
private String Key;
private int Value;

public SaveSettingsBO(int id, String key, int value) {
    this.Id = id;
    this.Key = key;
    this.Value = value;
}

public int getId() {
    return Id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.Id = id;
}

public String getKey() {
    return Key;
}

public void setKey(String key) {
    this.Key = key;
}

public int getValue() {
    return Value;
}

public void setValue(int value) {
    this.Value = value;
}
}
```

Java Code for this:

```
    List<SaveSettingsBO> paramsList = new ArrayList<>();         
    paramsList.add(new SaveSettingsBO(0, "Paymentmethod", 1));

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    HashMap<String, Object> serviceParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    serviceParams.put("accountSettingList", gson.toJson(paramsList));
```

> Is there a proper way to send array in request like this?

Or we should modify request to something like this:

[image]

Comment: gson.toJson(paramsList) convert this into string by adding ""+ at start of gson.toJson(paramsList)

Comment: gson.toJson(paramsList) returns String. So no need to cast it to String

Comment: post  SaveSettingsBO class

Comment: post your bean class

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to convert into Gson array

```
 JsonArray convertListToJSOnBox(ArrayList<CartItemBean> list) {

    JsonArray result = (JsonArray) new Gson().toJsonTree(list,
            new TypeToken<List<CartItemBean>>() {
            }.getType());


    return result;
}
```

and convert it into string .

Comment: @Zeero0 may be it will helpful for you

Comment: Let me try. Thanks for the help

Comment: Still null is received on server side

Comment: @Zeero0 why are you putting Gson into hashmap , you can send it directly

Comment: @Zeero0 Your log is printing Gson?

Comment: I think Volley only allows to send values in HashMap.

Comment: @Zeero0  can you send Gson object direct without adding into hashmap? and volley does not need hashmap , you can send json string directly

Comment: I didn't find way to send objects in POST request without Hashmap

Comment: @Zeero0  generally i send directly to sever after converting into gson

Comment: Post needs string parameters, it does not need any hash map, and remember you have to parse your json on server side also